# Phalcon router doesn't seem to be set

Tags: php, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I have set a custom route, my routes.php currently looks like this:

```
<?php
$router = new Phalcon\Mvc\Router();

$router->add('athlete/{username}', array(
    'controller' => 'athlete',
    'action' => 'index',
));

return $router;
```

In my services.php I'm setting the router:

```
$di->set('router', function() {
    return require __DIR__ . '/routes.php';
});
```

The index Action of my AthleteController looks like this, for testing purposes I'm passing the param to the view (`username`):

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $username = $this->dispatcher->getParam('username');

    if (!isset($username)) {
        $user = Users::findFirstByUsername($this->auth->getIdentity()['username']);
    } else {
        $user = Users::findFirstByUsername($username);
        if (!$user) {
            $this->flash->error('Could not find this user');
        }
    }
    $this->view->user = $user;
    $this->view->username = $username;
    $this->view->setTemplateBefore('public');
}
```

When I'm not using a custom param, it works, it can find the user and display his username. However, when I'm using for example the url `athlete/kerowan`, I get the error `Action 'kerowan' was not found on handler 'athlete'` whicht, to my understanding, means, that the router somehow isn't set correctly or doesn't catch the URL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago I had the same problem and I could not find anywhere in the docs or in the forum how to create route with optional params. The best solution I came up with is to have two routes if I want method to have different behaviour (like in your example). This will do the trick for you:

```
$router->add('/athlete/{username}', 'Athlete::index');
$router->add('/athlete', 'Athlete::index');
```

If someone has better/more elegant solution please share :)

Comment: And again thank you :) Seems odd, because in the Vokuro sample-app it seems to work. But whatever, this did the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

By default phalcon's router is using auto routing in this convention : `'/:module/:controller/:action/:params` in multimodule application and `'/:controller/:action/:params` in single module application. If you want to get rid from it then you have to pass false to router constructor.

Comment: Hmmm, the vokuro app doesn't pass false to the router constructor and it still works for them.

Comment: What action and controller you mean in vokuro ?

Comment: controller: UserControl, actions: confirmEmail and resetPassword. In fact, these are the only two actions routed in the vokuro routers.php